# How to Update Products Details using sku in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

How to Update product details using sku via script??
for example update description , short desc, price etc.. for a configurable product or a simple product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create folder in root of your system and create one php file inside those folder,

Keep below content in your file and run from browser,

```
<?php
// MAGENTO START
include('app/bootstrap.php');
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', '24-MB01');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    $product->setData('short_description', 'test description');
    $product->save();
    echo "Product Updated". " ";
}
```

Comment: Where to get the sku value in database??

Comment: You need to pass manually or need to get from csv file

Comment: Thank You Sir. I already passed it manually and works fine .But if i need to update for 100 products means how do i modify the above code and What are the fields i need to keep in my CSV file??

Comment: How do i import product details using SKU

Comment: You need to do $product->setData('description', 'long description');
    $product->save();

Comment: How to update configurable product description using sku via script??  I have used above code for config product,  It is failed to  function properly

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya  Is there right approach to do like this? if you want import product detail using csv then create command using console inside you custom module and update respective product details.

Comment: how to update categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Endpoint "**/rest/V1/products/xxxx**" (where XXX is the SKU) with a PUT request to update products.

The body would look something similar to -

```
{
 "product": {
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "description",
        "value": "What you want to change the description to"
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

For price -

```
{
   "product": {
   "price": 12.34
   }
}
```

Might be worth looking over the [Swagger documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html) and the [authentication needed](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) to use this.

EDIT:

I was using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test this. If you wanted a php / cURL script for this it would look something like:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "<YOUR SITE GOES HERE>/rest/V1/products/<SKU OF PRODUCT>",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\"product\": {\n\"price\": <PRICE GOES HERE>\n \n}\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"authorization: Bearer <BEARER TOKEN GOES HERE>",
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
// Whatever else you need to do if the request works goes here
}
```

Obviosuly filling in yhe details that are needed. You could make a simple HTML page before this that a user can fill in **SKU / PRICE/ DESCRIPTION** etc.

Or expand the script out further to work for as many products as needed.

Comment: Need clear explanation for this

Comment: Added an example Postman / PHP script for this.

Comment: I am totally new to magento 2 and I cannot understand your code. I wish to use php script to update product price or product description using sku.

Comment: This isn't Magento 2 specific - it's using PHP / cURL to update a product. It is using a specific Magento 2 endpoint to update the given product though. This endpoint needs to know the SKU of the product and what the changes are. It may be worth looking at some example cURL stuff to get an idea. Also using Postman makes this process a lot easier for testing.